# Select Hidden List Items with Growing=True

Tags: sapui5

I've a sap.m.Table with `growing(true)` and `growingThreshold` set to 5 and `MultiSelect` mode. Say, at any moment, the number of records in my JSON model is more than 5 (say 20). Hence, it will always do lazy loading.

I've a button which needs to select all the elements in my model i.e, 20 items. So, on click handler of a button i say : - `table.selectAll()`.

Now, I since only 5 items are shown in UI ( and in DOM), the UI5 library only selects which ever elements are shown.

`console.log('How many items selected ?', oTable.getSelectedContexts(true).length ) // says 5. But it needs to be 20.`

Question is - How do I select all items without loading them in UI ? Showing all elements to just select them does not make sense to me.

Now,

1. User will not click load more so many times to load all elements. There could be 100s of elements in real scenario. How to select all n elements in model ?
2. I do want to keep additional property in my model just to mark a item is selected or not ? Any suggestions are welcome.
3. User can select-all initially and then de-select few items which he doesnt mean. So, 20 items selected and say, removed first 2, so total no of selections should be 18. Any suggestions are welcome.

Code:

```
                    <ToggleButton text='Select All' press='onSelectAll'/>
                    <Button text='Submit' press='onSubmit' />
                    <Table noDataText="No Data" id="table0" items="{/}" mode='MultiSelect' growing='true' growingThreshold='5'>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem type="Active">
                                <cells>
                                    <Text text="{id}"/>
                                    <Text text="{name}"/>
                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                        <columns>
                            <Column id="column0">
                                <header>
                                    <Label text="ID" id="label0"/>
                                </header>
                            </Column>
                            <Column id="column1">
                                <header>
                                    <Label text="NAME" id="label1"/>
                                </header>
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                    </Table>
```

Controller :

```
    onInit: function () {
        var aData = [];
        for(var i =0;i< 20; i++) {
            var element = {
                id : 'I00' + i,
                name: 'Clone-' + i 
            };
            aData.push(element);
        }
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(aData);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },
    onSelectAll: function (oEvent) {
        var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
        var oTable = this.byId('table0');
        if (oSource.getPressed()) {
            oTable.selectAll();
        } else {
            oTable.removeSelections(true);
        }
    },
    onSubmit: function() {
        var oTable = this.byId('table0');
        console.log('How many items selected ?', oTable.getSelectedContexts(true).length );
    }
```

Comment: If your model is already a `JSONModel` then there is no real value in using the `growing` property as all data has already been loaded; it is then just a visual property. As for an `ODataModel` maybe it is better to handle the logic behind 'selecting all data' serverside as only the backend will have the full knowledge of all data

Comment: @Qualiture : We are not using oData Model rather an AJAX call to fetch data. Also, growing property is provided as data can be huge and there is no point showing user 100s of records. Since, UI5 removed pagination, growing is the only option we can use at this point.

Comment: Understand. But since the table selection is a control property rather than a model property (and the data is not yet fully loaded to the control itself yet) you may have to either extend your model with an extra boolean property which you then set at model level upon 'select all' and work from there, or handle the logic at backend level

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj Is that possible to select all items (if growing set to true) by using a multi-select default function? Or we need to create our own checkbox to achieve your scenario?

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj If ur value is already in the model, just get "table._bSelectAll" which returns true if select all selected. Then clear and refresh the model.